# Import messages from Exchange to Google Groups Collaborative Inbox

Tags: google-workspace, google-groups, import, exchange-server

At the moment we are an Exchange house and wanting to move to Google Apps. We currently have a shared inbox in Exchange that we want to move to *Google's Groups Collaborative Inbox* but there only seems to be a API to import old messages from Exchange.

While the API looks simple has any one written a script to do this?